# Initializing a set of structures and wrong data is showing up

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

So, I establish a static set of objects like this.

```
static struct rpn_name_type {
    const std::string name;
    e_search_in search_in;
    funct_op& op;
    std::any obj;
    std::any val;

}rpn_names[] = {
//conditionals
    {"group_and",       es_null,        group_and_or,       std::any(condition_type({true})),       std::any(and_type()) },
    {"group_and_end",   es_null,        group_and_or_end,   std::any(condition_type({false})),      std::any(and_type()) },
    {"group_or",        es_null,        group_and_or,       std::any(condition_type({true})),       std::any(or_type()) },
    {"group_or_end",    es_null,        group_and_or_end,   std::any(condition_type({false})),      std::any(or_type()) },
//project data
    {"percent_funded_1",es_project,     percent_funded_1,   std::any(),         std::any(tup_type_char_ii{})},
    {"expend_year_1",   es_project,     expend_year_1,      std::any(),         std::any(tup_type_char_ii{})},
//databaes data
    {"remain",          es_records,     remain,             std::any(),         std::any(int_pair_type{})},
    {"replace",         es_records,     replace,            std::any(),         std::any(int_pair_type{})},
    {"description_has", es_records,     description_has,    std::any(),         std::any(std::wstring{})},
//the nulllllllll
    {"null",            es_null,        null,               std::any(),         std::any()},
};
```

I had been setting the 'val' of created objects at run time for the 'es_project' and 'es_records'. But it was getting unwieldy to deal with every kind of op. I can greatly simplify my code if I just assign values on the condition of type.

But, either I'm missing something or there is a bug in the VS compiler. Because, for percent_funded_1' and 'expend_year_1' the val is 'and_type'. Those are just for IDs.

```
struct and_type {};
struct or_type {};
```

[image: screen shot at runtime]

```
using int_pair_type = std::pair<int32_t, int32_t>;
using tup_type_char_ii = std::tuple<const char*, int, int>;
```

So, those two entries are of type tuple, I would think it as fine as the others, but I get this weirdness.

**UPDATE**:
I'm going to fix it for now with this as I add the ops to the container:

```
        if (anop.name->search_in != es_null && anop.val.type() == typeid(and_type))
            anop.val = tup_type_char_ii{};
```

**UPDATE2:**

I should have said, I'm compiling with the latest VS2019. I was compiling with C++17 to get the error. By moving to the latest c++20 the problem went away.

Comment: Is there an actual defect in your code at run time, or is this about Visual Studio's debug visualizer?

Comment: Hi @IInspectable, yes. It was an `any_cast` exception that led me to hunt the above down. And I should have said, I'm using the latest VS2019 compiler with C++17 standard. I'll have to do some cleaning up to us the latest c++20, but I'm going to try that.

Comment: So, using the latest c++20, the issue goes away!  // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯